# An example of Dessin d'Enfants

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, planar-graphs, graph-embeddings

I'm self-studying the book of [Graphs on Surfaces and Their Applications, Lando & Zvonkin](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ereiner/Classes/Math8680Fall2014Papers/LandoZvonkin.pdf).
In Sec 2.3, we assume the form of an underlying polynomial in the Fig.2.20 below as
$$
f(x) = K \frac{(x - 1)^3 (x - a)}{x}
$$

[image]

And to work out the constant $K$, the authors go like

> by the fact that the function f − 1 has two double roots...

But I'm wondering like How do we know that it has two double roots?

Comment: Without reading through the whole text, I think the argument is that the dessin d'enfant shown omits the midpoint white vertices, which by definition correspond to $f^{-1}(1)$; that is, to the roots of $f - 1$. The degrees of those roots are the same as their degrees in the corresponding graph, namely $2$, and the sum of the degrees is $\deg f = 4$.

Comment: @anomaly Oh! the points $f^{-1}(1)$ (say x in this fibre) lead to $f(x) = 1$. Thus f - 1 = 0, right? This makes sense!
Sorry, the degree of this graph is 2 as one self-loop of 1 and another edge b/w 1 and a?

Comment: @anomaly, sorry do you know why this vertex 1 is called degree 3...?

Comment: Never mind! I opened another post for this question! Thank you!
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772481/degree-of-a-vertex-in-dessin-denfant

Comment: The black vertex at $1$ has degree $3$ (corresponding to the $(x -1)^3$ term in $f$); the white vertex that would be on the loop at $1$ has degree $2$.

Comment: @anomaly, Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!