# Degree of a vertex in Dessin d'Enfant

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, graph-embeddings

I'm self-studying the book of [Graphs on Surfaces and Their Applications, Lando & Zvonkin](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ereiner/Classes/Math8680Fall2014Papers/LandoZvonkin.pdf).
In Example 2.3.1 of Sec 2.3, the authors say, `the vertex 1 is of degree 3`.
Could someone tell me why so?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: A loop is like one edge leaving and another edge arriving, with incidence two. I guess you could view this as a useful convention. If you formally defined degree as the number of occurrences of that vertex as a source or a target of an edge then loops would contribute two because the loop views that vertex as both a source and a target

Comment: oh,, silly me.. thank you for your prompt response!